# Chrome 54 changes "page-break-after" behavior

Tags: google-chrome

I have printable content in my app that uses the "page-break-after" style to insert hard page breaks into the content. Until Chrome 54, it was working perfectly.  After the update, instead of a hard break it seems to insert vertical space into the layout instead.  Some trial and error attempts to overcome this have failed.  There are numerous previous questions here that question the implementation of page-break-after by Chrome, but nothing specific to this latest update that I can find.

Comment: I concur. I'm finding that this is resulting in pages not being made tall enough, with compounds with each additional page. (IE, EDGE, and Firefox are all fine.)